# Можно ли в if сделать проверку индекса массива на валидность и сразу проверить элемент массива?

Tags: c++

Есть массив array размером `N`. Есть индекс `i`, принимающий произвольное неотрицательное значение. 
Можно ли писать так:

```
if (i < N && array[i] > 5)
{
    ...
}
```

Может ли так произойти, что сначала выполнится второе сравнение (и тогда следует разбить условие на два `if`). Или все-таки можно оставить как есть?

Comment: Для операции && (И) условия выполняются слева-направо до первого условия, которое даст false. Соответственно в вашем случае условие `array[i]>5` будет проверено только в том случае, когда условие `i<N` истинно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, сначала выполнится первое сравнение и если i>N, то второе выполняться не будет.

Comment: Просто мне когда-то говорили, что компиллятор для оптимизации кода в некоторых случаях может менять порядок выражений. Ну ладно, спасибо

Comment: @yataw Тут стоит отметить, что в с++ есть некоторая неконсистентность в этом плане. Второй операнд не вычисляется только при вызове *встроенных* операторов логического и / или. Причем, в отличие от некоторых других языков, это поведение жестко задано и не подконтрольно программисту.

Answer (score 1):

Встроенные операторы `&&` и `||` группируются слева-направо. И если при вычислении части выражения уже очевиден конечный результат, то оставшаяся часть просто не вычисляется. [Вырезка из черновика](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and#1) стандарта про `&&`:

> The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 7).
>   The result is `true` if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees *left-to-right*
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

Comment: То, что надо. Спасибо!